# npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open

Tags: laravel, npm, command-prompt, npm-install, homestead

I am trying to install npm in a laravel homestead folder but i get these error messeges.
[error messages in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qUAq.png)

Comment: Instead of an image it would be great to share the issue directly in here for future references. Also, explain in detail what have you done to try and fix it and what has worked and what hasn't

Answer (score 1):

I've suffered with this issue for a long time and it seems that the problem is using *npm install* as a vagrant user inside a *laravel/homestead box* so the main issue is one of permissions on a synced folder which is the main task of Homestead.yaml.

Referenced in: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html

There's two solutions for this problem:

One will enable you to work from homestead normally, and the other is just like a patch of sorts.

Insert the next line just below your folder mapping on Homestead.yaml

```
type: "nfs"
```

Documentation of that here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead

Next option is just working from your system, that has all permissions since it owns the folder in wich you are working.

**Instead of executing npm install inside vagrant go to the folder in your system (your computer) and use the command from there.**

If you need to clean install your project use:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal from Homestead directory type `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`. After installing that plugin as said above add to Homestead.yaml file line `type: "nfs"` streight below folders mapping so it looks like:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/your_path/projects_folder
    to: /home/vagrant/code
    type: "nfs"
```

Then in terminal from Homestead directory `vagrant reload --provision`, `vagrant ssh`, cd to your project folder `cd code/project`. If installation failed before you can delete node_modules folder with `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install & npm run dev` again.